# Concurrent execution in Simulink real-time

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I have two model references - Slow model and Fast model, each running at its own rate for concurrent execution on the grt "generic real time" . However when I attempt to build the block I get the following error:

> Simulink cannot generate code for the signal at output port 1 of block
>   'Multirate/Fast' because the signal requires data transfer that
>   generates lock-free code for a rate monotonically scheduled task.

I am not sure what to configure in simulink to overcome this error. I attempted to add rate transition from the Fast model to the Slow model but the error remains.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many possibilites I can't give you a simple answer but you can try the following:

- Check if simulink can determine your sample rates... Did you configure that correctly (go to view and set sample rate colors) then you see if Simulink detects the execution times correctly.
- If your Simulink Block ('Fast') is contained in a single subsystem make it an atomic subsystem... an configure the sample rate on the subsystem properties.
- Set the strictest constrains in the rate transition block...
- How is your Model configuration? is it set to multitaskig....